# White Color when taping UIBar Button Item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a custom bar button item using the code below.

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-btn-next@2x.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0,57,44);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
```

and it's working fine, but the problem is that when I tap the button , I can see the white color in the center of the button (see screenshot). Can someone suggest to me the way to get rid of that?

[image]

Comment: Try to remove this line `[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Should be Write Answer

Remove Line

```
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

Try This than

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-btn-next@2x.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0,57,44);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove this line of code:

```
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

According to the documentation

```
showsTouchWhenHighlighted => A Boolean value that determines whether tapping the button causes it to glow.
```